# Vectorized use of the substring function for a row selection of a dataframe with different length

Tags: r

My dataframe has a column named Code of the type char which goes like b,b1,b110-b139,b110,b1100,b1101,... (1602 entries)

I am trying to select all the entries that match the strings in a vector and all the ones that start with the same string.

So lets say I have the vector

```
Selection=c("b114","d2")
```

then i want all codes like b114, b1140, b1141, b1142, ... as well as d2, d200, d2000, d2001, d2002, d2003 etc...

what does work in principle is to create a new dataframe like this:

```
bTable <- TreeMapTable[substr(TreeMapTable$Code,1,4)=="b114"|substr(TreeMapTable$Code,1,2)=="d2",]
```

which gives me all the data i want, but requires me to manually type the condition for each entry and i just want to give the script a vector with the strings.

I tried to do it like this:

```
SelectionL=nchar(Selection) 
Beispieltable <- TreeMapTable[substr(TreeMapTable$Code,1,AuswahlL)==Auswahl1,]
```

but this gives me somehow only half of the required entries and i confess i don't really know what it is doing. I know i could use a for loop but from everything i read so far, loops should be avoided and the problem should be solveable by use of vectors.

Comment: You could try `rowSums(mapply(function(x,y) substr(TreeMapTable$Code,1,y)==x, Selection, nchar(Selection)))>0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### sample data

```
df <- data.frame( Code = c("b114", "b115", "b11456", "d2", "d12", "d200", "db114"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Selection=c("b114","d2")
```

### answer

```
library( dplyr )
#create a regex pattern to filter on
pattern <- paste0( "^", Selection, collapse = "|" )
#filter out all rows wher 'Code' dows not start with the entries from 'Selection' 
df %>% filter( grepl( pattern, Code, perl = TRUE ) )

#     Code
# 1   b114
# 2 b11456
# 3     d2
# 4   d200
```

Comment: Thank you, this works quite well and by introducing me to the dplyr library you have given me some nice homework. Would you explain pls why the caret symbol in the paste0 function is needed?

Comment: @StevePiller: the `^` matches the 'start of the string'... so `^b114` 'hits' on `b11456`, but not on `fb114`... more reading on regex in R: http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html